# Unable to import Actor from cell.actors

Tags: celery, actor, kombu, remote-actors

```
from cell.actors import Actor
```

The above import produces an unresolved error in major IDEs like Pycharm.
Tried looking everywhere in the documentation of Celery/cell. The exact problem when ran in terminal looks as follows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ipublish' from 'kombu.common'
```

As explained on their website, Cell is an actor framework for Kombu, a messaging library for Python.

I checked everywhere in source files cell/actors.py and kombu/common.py for the error and the files seemed to be correct and no error in code. Therefore, there must be some environmental mismatch problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem partially. Installing specifically python3.7.0 is making the unresolved reference errors go away in the IDE, but still unable to create Actor and import 'dAgent'. Looked into source files and 'dAgent' must have been changed to 'Agent' class.

Still, no resolution for this error, although importing these objects from source files and providing the same inputs solves the unresolved reference error. But, the main error from kombu still exists.